# Python adds backslashes and quotes to user input file path, won't open

Tags: python

Using Python 3.9, I want to "input" a file path (via the input function). Then I want to open that file path. I am hindered by the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "'C:\\\\Users\\\\Hart\\\\Documents\\\\File.txt'"
```

I'm wondering why.

Here's what I know: I have a file path. According to os.path.exists, the file path exists.

```
>>> os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt")
True
```

I can open the file.

```
>>> open("C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt")
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I can call the file anything, and it still exists, and I can still open it.

```
>>> anything = "C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt"
>>> os.path.exists(anything)
True
>>> open(anything)
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

But I want to open the file indirectly, via the input function.

```
>>> file = input('Enter a file path\n')
Enter a file path
'C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt'
```

This creates a variable called file, which resembles my file path.

```
>>> print(file)
'C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt'
```

But when I try to open it...

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "'C:\\\\Users\\\\Hart\\\\Documents\\\\File.txt'"
```

Nor does the file represented by this variable exist.

```
>>> os.path.exists(file)
False
```

What's going on?

Comment: Backslashes in code are treated differently than backslashes entered via `input()`.  You only need one backslash, not two.

Comment: @JohnGordon same with the quotes.  Totally unnecessary when using `input()`.

Comment: When prompted to enter the file path, just enter it normally: i.e. `C:\Users\Hart\Documents\File.txt`.

Comment: Quotes and escaping are part of the syntax of literals in the program. They're not part of the data, and shouldn't be typed in input.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [String and Bytes Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) python string literals recognize escape sequences starting with the backslash (\) to encode things like newlines (\n), hex values (\x03) and etc. Notice that these rules apply to string *literals*, that is, strings in python source code that is compiled by python before use.

Strings read from other sources aren't literals and don't follow those rules. So, a string in python source code

```
file = "C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt"
```

is really

```
 C:\Users\Hart\Documents\File.txt
```

in memory. It can be hard to spot this because when you display the string, python may show you an escaped literal representation of the string. You can see the difference with a quick shell example

```
>>> test = "C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt"
>>> test
'C:\\Users\\Hart\\Documents\\File.txt'
>>> print(test)
C:\Users\Hart\Documents\File.txt
```

When you `input()` text, that is the real text, no a string literal. Windows doesn't want the quotes or the extra backslashes. So,

```
>>> file = input('Enter a file path\n')
Enter a file path
C:\Users\Hart\Documents\File.txt
>>> print(file)
C:\Users\Hart\Documents\File.txt
```